# Question 5, RMO 2003, issue with ratios

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, proof-explanation

In [problem 5, RMO 2003](http://olympiads.hbcse.tifr.res.in/uploads/rmo-sol-2003) a specific part of the solution depends on the following $$\dfrac{BD}{DC} = \dfrac{AE}{EC} = \dfrac{AF}{FB} = \dfrac{DC}{BD}$$[image: a reference diagram]

It is proven that $AB \parallel DE \: , BC \parallel FE \:, AC \parallel FD \:\:\:$ So I can see that $$\Delta EDC \sim \Delta ABC \implies \dfrac{BC}{DC} - 1 = \dfrac{AC}{EC} - 1$$

But how come this ratio continues to the next line $FD$?

Comment: Avoiding your specific issue ... It seems far easier to solve the problem by recognizing that $$\frac{d(A,BC)}{d(P,BC)} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}\,d(A,BC)\,|BC|}{\frac{1}{2}\,d(P,BC)\,|BC|} = \frac{|\triangle{ABC}|}{|\triangle PBC|}$$ so that equality of the ratios implies $$|\triangle PBC| = |\triangle APC| = |\triangle ABP|$$ Since the three areas sum to $|\triangle ABC|$, any one of them must therefore be one-third of that total, and we conclude that the common ratio is $3$. $\square$

Comment: @Blue Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. Wouldn't assuming $d(A,BC)$ equal to altitude restrict it to being a perpendicular?

Comment: The problem description defines $d(X,YZ)$ as "the perpendicular distance from $X$ to *line* $YZ$". So, $d(A, BC)$ *is* the length of the altitude from $A$, isn't it?

Comment: @Blue huh, guess I forgot about the specifics of the problem when I posted my last comment. Yeah that makes the problem much easier, thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

All equalities directly follow from the intercept theorem (take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) . You don't need to search for similar triangles.

- Equation $\dfrac{BD}{DC} = \dfrac{AE}{EC}$: $C$ is the intersection of $BC$ and $AC$. $AB$ is parallel to $ED$. So you can apply the intercept theorem.
- Equation $\dfrac{AE}{EC} = \dfrac{AF}{FB}$: $A$ is the intersection of $AC$ and $AB$. $FE$ is parallel to $BC$. So you can apply the intercept theorem.
- Equation $\dfrac{AF}{FB} = \dfrac{DC}{BD}$: $B$ is the intersection of $AB$ and $BC$. $FD$ is parallel to $AC$. So you can apply the intercept theorem.